# ID3 - base64 cannot set as src for img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64, id3

I just came the ID3 API across to get the cover of an audio file.
The base64 which is created by the API really good cannot be declarated in a `img` tag's `src`. The script don't even try to set a new `src` for the `img` tag.

https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

Here is my try:

```
<a class="uploaded_file"><img src="/symbol/audio.png"></a>

function getAudioCover(url) {
 var tags = ID3.getAllTags(url);

 var image = tags.picture;
 if (image) {
    var base64String = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < image.data.length; i++) {
        base64String += String.fromCharCode(image.data[i]);
    }
    var base64 = "data:" + image.format + ";base64," +
    window.btoa(base64String);
    return base64;
 }
 else {
    return "/symbol/audio.png";
 }
}

var uploadedFiles = 0;
var file_cover;
ID3.loadTags("audio.mp3", function() {
 file_cover = getAudioCover("audio.mp3");
 console.log(file_cover);
}, {
 tags: ["picture"]
});
$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img').attr("src", file_cover);
```

The console gives me this out: https://jsfiddle.net/f1wzbtyh/

How do I get this working?

Is there a overflow of string length for jquery or for src attribute?

Comment: The `data URL` at linked jsfiddle is a valid image file. Have you tried placing `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img').attr("src", file_cover);` within `.loadTags` callback function?

Comment: yes sir, tried and dont worked.

Comment: _"tried and dont worked."_ Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate? How did you retrieve `data URI`? Does `console.log(file_cover)` within `.loadTags` callback log `data URI` at `console`?

Comment: I realy want to but I just have all these things local (localhost). You have the API and the script. You just can try this for your self and then you can believe me this isn't working, at least not on chrome.

Comment: What does `console.log(file_cover);` log at `console`?

Comment: The base64 string. However it wont be placed in attr(). Thats my problem.

Comment: Is jQuery defined? Are there an errors logged at `console`? Is `javascript` which uses jQuery inside of `.ready()` handler?

Comment: _"Is there a overflow of string length for jquery or for src attribute?"_ No. The image should render correctly when `data URI` is set at `<img>` `src` https://jsfiddle.net/f1wzbtyh/2/ . Have you moved portion of `javascript` which sets `src` of `<img>` to `.loadTags` callback function?

Comment: Nope no errors. Thats the weird thing. Wait, might it be couse of .uploaded_file couse it's generated after the DOM.

Comment: _"Wait, might it be couse of .uploaded_file couse it's generated after the DOM."_ After `.loadTags` is called?

Comment: No. The element exists before .loadTags called.

Comment: Did you move `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img').attr("src", file_cover);` to `.loadTags` callback? If `data URI` is logged at `console`, there must be another issue. What does `console.log(file_cover, $('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img'))` log at `console` within `.loadTags` callback function? What is purpose of `var uploadedFiles = 0;` ? Is `javascript` at Question within a loop?

Comment: Yes I did and here is the result of console.log: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160921/83vmfvd6.png

Comment: `length:0` indicates that the element does not exist in `document` at the time the function is called

Comment: Solved! It was completly my fault. Im sorry to waste your time. I dont know why but somewhere in my code uploadedFiles were increased by 1. You see that in the screenshot. I was just wondered, couse the line above `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img').attr('name', uploadResults);` worked perfectly. Now I have to detect the troublemaker. I am mad and happy at the same time.

Comment: _"Solved! It was completly my fault."_ Curious if expected result is returned both where `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img').attr('name', uploadResults);` is within `.loadTags` callback function, and at line following callback function?

Comment: _"i dont know how the fuck it was even able to increase uploadedFiles before `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img')`?"_ If `.loadTags` returns results asynchronously, `uploadedFiles = uploadedFiles + 1;` could be called before the callback for `.loadTags` completes. This is reason suggested `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img')` be placed within `.loadTags` callback at Answer

Comment: Yeah, this was my thought too NOW. So you were a big helper I hope your not p*****ed of. I am thankful for your big help. Again I am sorry to waste your time.

Comment: *This is reason suggested* $('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img')` *be placed within .loadTags callback at Answer*. However this wont fix the problem.

Comment: _"However this wont fix the problem."_ Description of `uploadedFiles` being incremented does not appear at original Question. Is same result returned when `$('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')').find('img').attr("src", file_cover);` is placed after `.loadTags` callback? Where `uploadedFiles` variable is not incremented?

Comment: I think, if I took that line in .loadTags uploadedFiles would be increased by 1 couse of async. If it is outside file_cover is empty. Thats why I don't get any solution. Now I should increase uploadedFiles before .loadTags and begin with -1. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place call to `.attr()` within callback function. `file_cover` may not be defined when referenced outside of `.loadTags` call.

```
ID3.loadTags("audio.mp3", function() {
 file_cover = getAudioCover("audio.mp3");
 console.log(file_cover);
 $('.uploaded_file:eq(' + uploadedFiles + ')')
 .find('img').attr("src", file_cover);
}, {
 tags: ["picture"]
});
```